# Need help with finding if a function has a name.

Tags: terminology, online-resources

I watched a first year senior year class in China and saw a function on the board.

$$ H^n_x = x(x+1)(x+2)\cdots (x+n-1)$$

you can see a similar problem [here](http://www.jyeoo.com/math2/ques/detail/8c64efc6-08ed-4b1e-a6af-6e5169321cb7) in Chinese.

I think this function has name, but I haven't found it.  I have searched Stirling Formula, Gamma Function, etc but haven't found this particular function.

My question is does $H^n_x$ have a specific name and help me find some resources to read more about this function.

Comment: This function is a polynomial, if that's the name you're looking for. It's the polynomial with yeroes at $0,-1,-2,\dots, -n+1$.

Comment: It can be expressed in terms of the gamma function:$$H_x^n={\Gamma(x+n)\over\Gamma(x)}$$

Comment: @5xum I know that it is a polynomial, that is not a specific name for a particular function, that is a specific name for a general class of functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Rising factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol)** though Wikipedia also calls it the "Pochhammer function", "Pochhammer polynomial", "ascending factorial", "rising sequential product" or "upper factorial"

Comment: That was what I was looking for, I didn't think it was a very famous and with an agreed name, but I figured it had a name.